# Spark load model and continue training

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm using **Scala** with **Spark 2.0** to train a model with **LinearRegression**.

```
val lr = new LinearRegression()
  .setMaxIter(num_iter)
  .setRegParam(reg)
  .setStandardization(true)

val model = lr.fit(data)
```

this is working fine and I get good results.
I saved the model and loaded it in another class to make some predictions:

```
val model = LinearRegressionModel.load("models/LRModel")
val result = model.transform(data).select("prediction")
```

Now I wanted to continue training the model with new data, so I saved the model and loaded it to continue the training.

Saving:

```
model.save("models/LRModel")
lr.save("models/LR")
```

Loading:

```
val lr = LinearRegression.load("models/LR")
val model = LinearRegressionModel.load("models/LRModel")
```

The Problem is, when I load the model, there is not `fit` or `train` function to continue the training.
When I load the LinearRegression object it seems like it does not save the weights, only the parameters for the algorithm.
I tested it by training the same data for the same number of iterations and the result was the exact same `rootMeanSquaredError` and it was definitely not converged at this point of learning.
I also can not load the model into the LinearRegression, it results in a error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel.<init>(java.lang.String)
```

So the question is, how do I get the LinearRegression object to use the saved LinearRegressionModel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pipeline to save and load the machine learning models.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel
val lr = new LinearRegression().setLabelCol("labesl").setFeaturesCol("features").setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(1.0).setElasticNetParam(1.0)

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(lr))

pipeline.fit(trainingData)

pipeline.write.overwrite().save("hdfs://.../spark/mllib/models/linearRegression");

val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("hdfs://...")

sameModel.transform(assembler).select("features", "labels", "prediction").show(
```

Comment: Here also you are predicting/transforming new data instead of retraining/fitting it.